# Polymer vs Ionic for mobile app?

Tags: polymer, ionic-framework

I plan to develop mobile app. I came across ionic and polymer framework. Which one is best for mobile UI and performance?

Comment: I'll just want to mention that JQuery Mobile is unreliable and people shouldn't use it, and asking between Polymer/Ionic is a smart decision.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I am getting confusion of picking framework :P

Answer (score 8):

First, before choosing any of these frameworks you need to know.

Ionic is based on Angular.js which is a very powerful framework for building SPA and Ionic uses Angular's Directives to make custom HTML tags.

But whereas Polymer is just a library that makes extensive use of Web Components(New set of standards developed by the W3C and is not implemented by all browsers and previous releases of Android).

Up until now Polymer has been only an experiment so it's not production ready to be used for deployment, but this could change soon after `Polymer 0.8` is released.

After knowing some info about these frameworks, I would go for Ionic cause I know it is widely used by developers and is production ready, on the other hand if you wish to wait for Polymer 0.8 to be released(expected by March-2015,)it has it's own set of features that are worth waiting for.

Comment: Apparently, Polymer is now also "production ready". It looks polished but I'd still use Ionic since its a more mature framework.

Answer (score 0):

> Unlike other frameworks, Polymer and its polyfills are intended to
>   work in the latest version of “evergreen” browsers. This means that
>   your favorite browser might not be supported. https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/resources/compatibility.html

So unless you can afford to sacrifice compatibility, go with the safer choice.

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant. This is a mobile app where people will have the latest browsers on android and iOS devices.

Comment: People don't always have the latest browser on Android or iOS.

Comment: Older browsers use polyfills that support IE10+, its like having virtual dom implementation by your framework that stamps out elements if browser API doesn't support it out of the box.

Answer (score -2):

I think Polymer not suitable for mobile development until you don't have a strong UI framework for it (like Ionic).

If you want use Polymer because you don't like Angular part of Ionic (like me :D) I suggest you try [Meteoric-124](https://github.com/meteoric124/meteoric) (that one of the best [Meteoric](https://github.com/meteoric/meteor-ionic) fork with many bug-fix, improvement, [docs](http://meteoric-doc.com), [demo](http://meteoric-demo.com/) and more) if you want use **Ionic in Meteor without Angular**.

Or try [React-Ionic](https://github.com/reactionic/reactionic) if you want use **Ionic in React without Angular**.

Comment: Polymer provides FULL material (mobile first) design support. Which is more complete than angular 1/2 counterparts for example.

Comment: Please provide references for your comment. `Which is more complete than angular 1/2 counterparts for example.`

Comment: Polymer had first complete implementation of material design and has(had?) the biggest catalog of elements created directly by google.